# Using LEFT JOIN to returns rows that don't have a match

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a situation where we have a table that contains all the items, if the item was sold it has an entry in another table.

I am trying to get all the items returned that have **not** been sold, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT a.auction_id FROM auctions AS a 
LEFT JOIN winners AS w ON a.auction_id=w.auction_id AND w.winner_id IS NULL
WHERE a.owner_id=1234567 AND a.is_draft=0 AND a.creation_in_progress=0;
```

I thought this would only return items from the `auctions` table that don't have a matched entry in the `winners` table since I am doing `AND w.winner_id IS NULL`.

However it seems to still return the same amount of rows as it does when I leave off `AND w.winner_id IS NULL`.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. (although I think you just want to move IS NULL to the where clause)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I've never noticed any issues with that before; I used to put them in the WHERE part but then read it's better to put them in the ON part as MySQL can then optimize the query better; though thinking about it, it may depend on what the condition is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.auction_id
  FROM auctions AS a
  LEFT JOIN winners AS w
    ON a.auction_id = w.auction_id
 WHERE a.owner_id = 1234567
   AND a.is_draft = 0
   AND a.creation_in_progress = 0
   AND w.winner_id IS NULL
```

This belongs in the WHERE clause:

```
   AND w.winner_id IS NULL
```

Criteria on the outer joined table belongs in the ON clause when you want to ALLOW nulls. In this case, where you're filtering in on nulls, you put that criteria into the WHERE clause. Everything in the ON clause is designed to allow nulls.

Here are some examples using data from a question I answered not long ago:

Proper use of where x is null:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8936b5/2/0

Same thing but improperly placing that criteria into the ON clause:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8936b5/3/0

(notice the FUNCTIONAL difference, the result is not the same, because the queries are not functionally equivalent)

Comment: Thanks..... as per my comment above I used to put them in the WHERE part but then read it's better to put them in the ON part as MySQL can then optimize the query better; but I guess it depends on what the condition is for?

Comment: @Brett . . . I don't think MySQL cares whether conditions are in the `on` clause or the `where` clause for optimization purposes (most databases don't).  Where did you hear that it is better for performance to put the conditions there?

Comment: @Brett there is a functional difference because of your intentions. It depends. Are you talking about inner or outer joins? In outer joins you almost always want to put CRITERIA - join conditions aside - into the ON clause, so as to allow nulls (that is the nature of an outer join). If you were to put them in the WHERE clause, you would turn the outer join into an inner join. When you want to FILTER IN ON NULLS of an outer joined table, you HAVE to use the WHERE clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Honestly I can't remember. I'm guessing it's because they are separated if you don't put them in the ON part as that's what it's joining on; but I guess it was my bad as I already had the condition for the `JOIN` so I should have just put it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Brett the join in your on clause allows nulls to come back. If you want to limit the results to nulls, you have to use the WHERE clause. It is not a question of performance, that is how you do what you want to do. If you were to put it into the ON clause, you would not get the same result, because it is not functionally equivalent. There is a functional difference between the ON clause and WHERE clause with outer joins.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. Basically anything can go in the ON clause unless you are filtering on NULLs?

Comment: With inner joins it is considered good practice to use the ON clause rather than the WHERE clause, however it won't actually change the result of the query because they are functionally equivalent. With outer joined tables, yes, always use the ON clause unless you want to filter in on null values. Because in the ON clause, w/ an outer joined table, all criteria essentially has ("or the outer joined table's columns don't match") implied. The possibility of nulls is always allowed, no matter what criteria you put into the ON clause (of an outer joined table).

Comment: So by you putting that into the ON clause, you're saying the outer joined table is ALLOWED to have nulls, not that it HAS to have nulls. If you want the outer joined table to absolutely have ONLY nulls, then yes, you must use the WHERE clause. And all other criteria related to the outer joined table should go into the ON clause, otherwise your outer join would be turned into an inner join.